# In Jenkins declarative pipeline how to get all parameter values

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am having a jenkinsfile where I have defined "CascadeChoiceParameter" parameter and this parameter will return values like "ABC","PQR" and "WRQ". Now, I want to show all this parameter values and store it as a list.

So, I know in extended choice parameter we can import below plugins and write a code to get all jenkins parameter values as shown below.

```
import hudson.model.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.*
import com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition

def param = getParam(JOB_NAME, "Services")
                    def all_param_values =  param.getValue().replaceAll("\\s","").tokenize(',').tail()
                    def service_name = ("${SERVICE_NAME}".replace('Services:', '')).toString().tokenize(',[]')
```

So, in my case to get all jenkins parameter values for "CascadeChoiceParameter" parameter I have imported below plugins and written below code:-

```
import hudson.model.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.*
import org.biouno.unochoice.CascadeChoiceParameter

@NonCPS
def getJob(name) {
    def hi = Hudson.instance
    return hi.getItemByFullName(name, Job)
}

@NonCPS
def getParam(String jobName, String paramName) {
    def job = getJob(jobName)
    def prop = job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
    for (param in prop.getParameterDefinitions()) {
        if (param.name == paramName) {
            return param
        }
    }
    return null
}

def param = getParam(JOB_NAME, "Test")
def all_param_values =  param.getValue().replaceAll("\\s","").tokenize(',').tail()
def Test_name = ("${TEST_NAME}".replace('Test:', '')).toString().tokenize(',[]')
```

But, while running jenkins job I am getting below error.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.biouno.unochoice.CascadeChoiceParameter.getValue() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Can anyone assist?